# meteor, Error: Method not found, trying to test with velocity

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I am a bit new to meteor. I am trying to write some unit tests for a meteorite app someone wrote, and I am having some trouble with some package stuff.

When running `mrt` (er, `sudo mrt` because otherwise I get a permissions error, but that's a different issue), a Proxy is started, MongoDB is started, Jasmine-Unit is loaded, and Kadira completes instrumenting the app, but then I get this:

```
W20140717-16:13:43.277(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20140717-16:13:43.278(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/Tyler/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140717-16:13:43.278(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140717-16:13:43.278(-4)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140717-16:13:43.297(-4)? (STDERR) Error: Method not found [404]
W20140717-16:13:43.297(-4)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.apply (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1378)
W20140717-16:13:43.298(-4)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.call (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1348)
W20140717-16:13:43.298(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/server/js/server.js:6:8
W20140717-16:13:43.298(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/server/js/server.js:13:3
W20140717-16:13:43.299(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Tyler/Documents/TylersAwesomeDocuments/ProgrammyStuff/AdTribStuff/Repos/djmustard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140717-16:13:43.299(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140717-16:13:43.300(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/Tyler/.meteor/tools/858c88b520/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140717-16:13:43.300(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Tyler/Documents/TylersAwesomeDocuments/ProgrammyStuff/AdTribStuff/Repos/djmustard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

I'm not really sure what to make of it. `livedata` is not in the packages directory. Not sure how to debug this. Any help with the error itself or how to go about figuring it out? Thanks!

EDIT:

at app/server/js/server.js:6:8

```
6  Meteor.call('S3config', {
7      key: '<key>',
8      secret: '<secret>',
9      bucket: '<bucket>',
10     directory: '<directory>'
11 });
```

Comment: did you look at server/js/server.js:6:8?

Comment: I edited to show app/server/js/server.js

Comment: It says that the Meteor method S3config is not found. The error looks self-explanatory?

Comment: It looked like some method in packages/livedata/livedata_server.js wasn't being found. Regardless, understanding the error is nice, but fixing it is another thing entirely. Turns out when I replace `Meteor.call('S3config', ` with `S3.config = ` it works out. Thanks for the pointer to server/js/server.js! Not sure why I didn't go right there.